# Create Graph actions with GET

Tags: facebook, curl, facebook-graph-api, graph

```
curl -F 'access_token=AAAAASrf1VhwBAOU0pZAzvwBYQLjcJClsMA2e7al0qsRP5uJ0KoUmMuc7aNq56gXmSQd6c2h9vfdQUscvtC3ZAZCxP36USGFy0fNqdhq5gZDZD' \
 -F 'article=http://example.com' \
    'https://graph.facebook.com/me/teglilka:iztegli'
```

Is this the only way to set action, is there GET method ?

Comment: Tried the docs? -F is a POST...

Comment: The graph API supports simulated POST requests by adding a ?method=POST parameter to the call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph API supports simulated POST requests by adding a `?method=POST` parameter to the call